# testing invalid enum values use method Enum.IsDefined(typeof())

Tags: c#

I have enum (`Months`) and I have a method called `Readmonths`. if the user enters `13` that's means invalid months number if the user entered 8 the program returns August.

My question is how can test the invailid enum by using this method specifally { **testing invalid enum values use method **`Enum.IsDefined(typeof())` }**

here is my code:

```
Month ReadMonth(string question)
        {
            Console.Write(question);
            int monthNumber = int.Parse(Console.ReadLine());
            return (Month)monthNumber;  
        }
```

Comment: Well, you'd pass in `typeof(Month)` and `monthNumber`...

Comment: But you might want to use the generic form instead: `Month month = (Month) monthNumber; if (!Enum.IsDefined(month)) { ... }`

Comment: @JonSkeet thank you for ur reply. sorry I didn't get it. and how can add the true and false in that why ?

this is the question what says:  for
testing invalid enum values use method Enum.IsDefined(typeof(Month), ...) that returns true
or false. Continue reading a month number until Enum.IsDefined returns true

Comment: It's unclear what the problem is, to be honest. It sounds like you probably want to use a `while` loop or a `do`/`while` loop, calling the method to determine whether the value is valid. But we don't know whether you're struggling to call the method, or struggling to work it into a loop.

Comment: @JonSkeet is too nice to suggest that you may want to read the fine manual https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.enum.isdefined?view=net-5.0 that shows examples of how to use the method. (Feel free to flag this comment as rude or offensive as linking to documentation is flat out rude).

Answer (score 1):

So you just need a working example? Here you go.

```
using System;

namespace ConsoleApp1
{
    static class Program
    {
        enum Month
        {
            January = 1,
            February = 2,
            March = 3,
            April = 4,
            May = 5,
            June = 6,
            July = 7,
            August = 8,
            September = 9,
            October = 10,
            November = 11,
            December = 12
        }

        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            Month month = ReadMonth("What month is it?");

            // do something with the news
            if (DateTime.Now.Month == (int)month)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Right, it's {0}; forgot about that.", month);
            }
            else
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Ahm, no; doesn't feel like {0}", month);
            }

            // wait before exiting
            Console.ReadKey();
        }

        static Month ReadMonth(string question)
        {
            // declare helper
            int monthNo = 0;
            // write question
            Console.WriteLine(question);
            // type conversion with TryParse
            if (int.TryParse(Console.ReadLine(), out monthNo))
            {
                // test value against enum
                if (Enum.IsDefined(typeof(Month), monthNo))
                {
                    // return result
                    return (Month)monthNo;
                }
            }
            // do something, we didn't get proper input
            throw new InvalidCastException();
        }
    }
}
```